Use a smart contract as signer in hardhat test
I have two smart contracts depend on each other
contract A {
    function isOK() external bool view {...}
}

contract B {
    address _contractA;

    modifier onlyContractA() {
        if (msg.sender != _contractA) {
            revert();
        }
    }

    function setContractA(address addr) external onlyOwner {
        _contractA = addr;
    }

    function doSth() external onlyContractA {
        A a = A(_contractA);

        if (!a.isOK()) {
            revert();
        }
    }
}

I want the state of B can only be modified by A so doSth can only be called by the address set by setContractA. In doSth, it checks the state (thus view-only function) of A to determine if it's doable.
When I'm writing unit tests for B, I need to setContractA first to make the function doSth work. If I set it to a regular signer, there's no problem to call doSth with that signer, but the isOK will fail as the contractA address is set to a signer instead of a contract. However, if I set contractA to the deployed address of contract A, I have no idea to call doSth with contract A as the signer. Is it doable?
Or this is not a good practice to let two smart contracts depend on each other? If so what's a better solution?
